# How to use async on an empty interface method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, syntax

Say I have an interface

```
interface IFoo {
    Task SomeMethodAsync();
}
```

And I wanted to implement this interface, but for one class the method is blank.

Should I live with the warning this produces?

```
async Task SomeMethodAsync() {}
```

Or should I have it return some dummy task?

```
async Task SomeMethodAsync() { await Task.Run(() => {}); }
```

Or is there another option?

Also I want to implement this method as an explicit interface method. Will that make any difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interfaces and async methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573516/interfaces-and-async-methods)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Methods that return `Task` do not have to be `async`.

I would recommend something like this:

```
Task IFoo.SomeMethodAsync()
{
  return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

I'm assuming that if this was a synchronous method, you would just have an empty method body; this is the `async` equivalent of an empty method body.

Answer (score 2):

It depends only how do you decide that framework has to handle such cases.

You have, imo, several options :

- raise an exception (will break immidiately execution, and you have to *handle* it in some way in some place in execution chain).
- return `default-value` (that can be a solution offered by you: just an empty task that doesn't do anything. Bad about this is that I call function *expecting* it does something, it doesn't notify me about anything but do not do anything either. Imo, this is bad design.
- return some `not-valid-value`, which intercepted by caller so caller "knows" that something *is not ok*.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this with an abstract base class. I tried Stephen Cleary's method, but was getting compiler errors in C# 6.

An example of my base method:

```
protected abstract Task OnFoo(Bar bar);
```

This is what I had to do in my derived class:

```
protected override async Task OnFoo(Bar bar)
{
    await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

The problem with the other answer was the `return` keyword in the phrase. Because the return value of `Task` is essentially `void`, you can't return anything. Also, the `await` keyword is required.