# c# interface implementation async await

Tags: c#, interface, async-await

Ok! This is already stressing me for few hours.

I'm using a provided assembly that has an interface I need to implement

```
public interface ICustomInterface
{
      CustomType DoSomething(string name);
}
```

in my code I do like this:

```
public class MyClass: ICustomInterface
{
   public MyClass()
   {
   }

   // now I should implement the interface like this

   public CustomType DoSomething(string name)
   {
          CustomType nType = new CustomType();

          // do some work

          return nType;
   }
}
```

So far so good but in my implementation of the interface in the MyClass I need to make use of `async await` therefore the implementation should be like this:

```
    public class MyClass: ICustomInterface
{
   public MyClass()
   {
   }

   // now I should implement the interface like this

   public async Task<CustomType> DoSomething(string name)
   {
          CustomType nType = new CustomType();

          await CallSomeMethodAsync();

          // do some extra work

          return nType;
   }
}
```

And of course this doesn't work because it complains the Interface `ICustomerInterface.DoSomething....` is not implemented.

Is there a way to override the interface implementation that accepts async await?

I cannot modify the provided assembly.

Comment: look here for answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573516/interfaces-and-async-methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's impossible.  If the interface requires the operation to be computed synchronously, then the operation needs to be performed synchronously.

Comment: And how will I then use my async operation within it?

Comment: @DavidDury Either perform the operation synchronously, instead of asynchronously, or don't implement the interface (possibly using a different interface instead).  This is of course since you can't modify the interface in question.

Comment: I was expecting this answer, kind of tried everything for the last 3 hours ...  but thanks for clarification!